# Format date according user locale with date-fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

I'm using `date-fns` and I would like to display dates as per user’s selected locale (language+region) for example: **“Jan 12, 2021” for en_US** or **“12 Jan 2021.” for en_CA.**, There is a way to achieve this with `date-fns`?

Comment: Use the `PP` pattern with `format`: https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/format

Comment: can you post a more complete answer and how the user's locale would fit into your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `P` patterns to `format` deal with localization: https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/format

Looks like you would want the `PP` variant and can be used like this:

```js
import { caLocale } from 'date-fns/locale/ca'

const result = format(new Date(2021, 0, 12), "PP", {
  locale: caLocale
})
```